# How is `va_list` implemented in Assembler level on ARMv7 Android?

Tags: assembly, arm

I need to extract all arguments from `CallStaticObjectMethodV` JNI call on ARMv7 Android at Assembler level.

Can anyone advice how is `va_list` implemented on low level in ARMv7 Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *Procedure Call Standard for the ARM® Architecture* (ARM IHI 0042E):

Typedef: `va_list`

Base type:

```
struct __va_list {
void *__ap;
}
```

Notes:

> A `va_list` may address any object in a parameter list. Consequently,
>   the first object addressed may only have word alignment (all objects
>   are at least word aligned), but any double-word aligned object will
>   appear at the correct double-word alignment in memory. In C++,
>   `__va_list` is in namespace `std`.

So basically it's just a pointer to the word-aligned arguments in memory.